# How to fix this rdlc local report processing error which occures when setting the report parameters

Tags: c#, sqlite, rdlc

I want to save a rdlc report without using the report-viewer and I was successful without the report parameters,as when i tried to add report parameters to report i got and "report processing error".

I tried to save report without parameters and it worked but as soon as i add parameters it generates this error.

```
try
{
                using (IDbConnection db = new SQLiteConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["cs"].ConnectionString))
                {
                    if (db.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
                    {
                        db.Open();
                    }
                    string getOrderItems = "Select * from OrderItems where OrderId = 20";
                    List<OrderItem> orderItems = db.Query<OrderItem>(getOrderItems, commandType: CommandType.Text).ToList();
                    OrderItemBindingSource.DataSource = orderItems;
                }
                LocalReport orderReceipt = new LocalReport();
                orderReceipt.ReportPath = @"D:\ADiTM\Products\ADiTmPoS\ADiTmPoS\Reports\OrderReceipt.rdlc";
                ReportDataSource rds = new ReportDataSource();
                rds.Name = "orderItem";
                rds.Value = this.OrderItemBindingSource;
                orderReceipt.DataSources.Add(rds);
                ReportParameter[] parameters = new ReportParameter[]
                {
                    new ReportParameter("CustomerName",orderDetail.CustomerName),
                    new ReportParameter("CustomerContactNumber",orderDetail.CustomerContactNumber),
                    new ReportParameter("CustomerAddress",orderDetail.CustomerAddress),
                    new ReportParameter("OrderId",orderDetail.Id.ToString()),
                    new ReportParameter("Date",orderDetail.Date.ToString("MM/DD/yyyy")),
                    new ReportParameter("Status",orderDetail.Status),
                    new ReportParameter("StaffName",orderDetail.StaffName),
                    new ReportParameter("StaffMobileNumber",orderDetail.StaffMobileNumber),
                    new ReportParameter("UserName",orderDetail.UserName)

                };
                orderReceipt.SetParameters(parameters);

                Byte[] mybytes = orderReceipt.Render("PDF");
                using (var fbd = new FolderBrowserDialog())
                {
                    DialogResult result = fbd.ShowDialog();
                    if (result == DialogResult.OK && !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(fbd.SelectedPath))
                    {
                        using (FileStream fs = File.Create(fbd.SelectedPath + "OrderReceipt22.pdf"))
                        {
                            fs.Write(mybytes, 0, mybytes.Length);
                        }
                        MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, "Order Receipt Saved", "Success!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
                    }

                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, ex.Message, "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            }
```

I use breakpoints and it gives error on

```
orderReceipt.SetParameters(parameters);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is an annoying error message, but there has been a little-known improvement which you should be able to exploit as long as your rdlc runtime version is > 2015: look into the `InnerException`, and attach a handler to the [ReportError event](https://colinmackay.scot/2011/08/18/friendly-error-messages-with-microsoft-report-viewer-control/).

```
orderReceipt.ReportError += new EventHandler(orderReceipt_ReportError);
```

and

```
private void orderReceipt_ReportError(object sender, ReportErrorEventArgs e)
{
    MetroFramework.MetroMessageBox.Show(this, e.Exception.ToString(), "Failed!", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
    e.Handled = true;
}
```

There will be details about which parameter is the culprit and what's wrong with it. frequent causes: misspelling, type mismatch, nullability mismatch.

Comment: I collected the inner exception and it says "the definition of the report is invalid"

Comment: you'll also need the handler for the `ReportError` event. it will receive more details, including the name of the first parameter that fails (if it really is a parameter issue, after all - I had this also with version mismatches between rdlc file version and engine version).